# Routing subdirectories

Tags: routes, kohana-3

In Kohana 3.2 how do you set up a route to accept multiple directories i.e.

```
http://example.com/foo/bar/controller/action/id
```

It should also accept:

```
http://example.com/foo/controller/action/id
http://example.com/foo/bar/baz/controller/action/id
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Route::set('foo', 'foo(/<controller>(/<action>(/<id>)))')
    ->defaults(array(
            'directory'  => 'foo',
            'controller' => 'index',
    ));

Route::set('foobar', 'foo/bar(/<controller>(/<action>(/<id>)))')
    ->defaults(array(
            'directory'  => 'foo/bar',
            'controller' => 'index',
    ));
```

... or ...

```
Route::set('directory', '<directory>(/<controller>(/<action>(/<id>)))',
    array(
        'directory' => '.*',
    ))
    ->defaults(array(
        'controller' => 'index',
    ));
```